# A service doesn't start on my Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, unicorn

I've added my `unicorn_myapp` to `sudo update-rc.d unicorn_appname defaults`, so it could be executed, when server starts. But it doesn't.
For some reason, when I do `sudo service unicorn_myapp start`, it gives me the following error:

```
Job for unicorn_myapp.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status unicorn_myapp.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I execute `journalctl -xe`, it gives me:

```
Jul 26 11:18:34 mirr-main unicorn_myapp[2771]: /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp: 1: eval: bundle: not found
Jul 26 11:18:34 mirr-main systemd[1]: unicorn_myapp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jul 26 11:18:34 mirr-main systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Manage unicorn server.
```

But when I start it like this: `sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start`, it starts and unicorn begins to work. `unicorn_myapp` is a symlink to `unicorn_init.sh` that is located in my `project/config` dir. But when I restart the server, unicorn doesn't start. What are the ways to fix it? Thank ahead.

Comment: The `bundle` executable is not present in `$PATH`.

Comment: How can I add it?

Comment: how do you install ruby, as system package or user based with rvm or otherwise?

Comment: ruby is installed via rvm